# My Shape Key moves unwanted parts of mesh

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

When I used my (blinking eye) shape key it rotates the left shoulder. I checked weights its not that, I checked to make sure I didn't accidently select it when creating the shape key not that either. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.[image: Blue arrows is where rotation happens]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your basis shape is correct, you can enter Edit Mode for your Blink shapekey, select the shoulder verts, and use Vertex > Blend from Shape, uncheck Add and make sure the Shape is set to Basis and Blend is set to 1.

[image: Blend from Shape]

Comment: Thanks so much that worked!